# What are allowed characters for a submodule name in registerModule?

Tags: typo3, extbase

[registerModule()](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/BackendModules/BackendModuleApi/Index.html) expects a submodule key as a third parameter.

I think it should probably not contain a space and only alphabetic characters (or alphanumeric?) and underscore ('_'), but I'm not really sure.

I could not find specific information for this.

Comment: it can be probably alphanumeric, just the first character might be required being alphabetic.

Answer (score 0):

The function makes use of \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase to generate the full module name combined of main module and sub module connected with an _

So you already guessed the right answer.

Comment: Still not sure about allowed characters. I would probably just use lowercase a-z to be on the safe side. But I wanted to update some documentation recently and it would be good to *know*, not just guess.

Comment: underscoredToUpperCamelCase means: You can use underscores, but they will be removed and the following letter as well as the first letter will be converted to upper case. So you can use alphanumeric characters and the underscore. what_ever, whatever, what1_ever2 should be correct - not sure about 1what_2ever though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated strange to answer!

Official [API document](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_utility.html#aaf137b0e8f46ae67d1eab38e1db56c06) does not provide exact information. I have worked around some extension which has multiple sub-module. I'm quite sure this not allow special character as you sub-module key.

eg. web_TestTestbe123 (mainModulename_subModuleKey)

I have noticed bellow characteristic for the key:

- Key must be lowercase
- No space allowed
- Numerica value would be fine

Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I noticed the documentation does not provide an exact answer. That's why I asked. Your answer looks good, but I am hoping to get an official confirmation. If yes, I'll add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the documentation just now:

```
Backend modules

1. The modkey is made up of alphanumeric characters only. It does not contain underscores and starts with a letter.
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/NamingConventions/Index.html